# React Link not working in an independant component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**Apps.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import UrlList from "./pages/UrlList";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/url-list">
            <UrlList />
        </Route>
      </Switch>  
      </Router>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Home File**

```
import Body from '../components/body/Body';
import Footer from '../components/footer/Footer';
import Header from '../components/header/Header';
import './Home.css';

const Home = () => {
    return(<div>
        <Header />
        <Body />
        <Footer />    
    </div>)
}

export default Home;
```

**Here is my Header.js File**

```
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Link
  } from "react-router-dom";


const Header = () => {
    return(
        <Router>
            <div>
                <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <Link to="/url-list">URL Lists</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

So, on default Root URL that is localhost:3000/

The page gets displayed, with Header containing two links.
When I click on the UrlList , it does click, even the Browser windows's URL changes to localhost:3000/url-list as well, BUT, BUT, the page does not change.

Unless, if I manually reload the page now, and then the URLList page does load up.

What am I don'g wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<Router>` should enclose your `App` component, so it should be like this instead:

```
<Router>
   <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/url-list">
            <UrlList />
        </Route>
      </Switch>  
      
    </div>
</Router>
```

I think that you shouldn't insert it in your `Home`, just keep the `Link` there, like so:

```
const Header = () => {
    return(
            <div>
                <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <Link to="/url-list">URL Lists</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
    )
}
```

#### Take a look at the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) :)

Comment: Oh, i should not be having router component wrapped around my Link component is what you mean right? Yes, that seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you only want one Router component and it goes around everything.

Comment: @PrakharSharma Yes exactly :)